# When to use 'by' instead of 'at' or 'on' to specify time/date?

Tags: prepositions, time, dates

We use "by" to specify time or date, as in

> I have to go by 9 am.

We can also use "at" here. When to use "by" / "on" / "at"?

When "by" should be preferred over "before" or "till"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. [by](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by?s=t)
>      not later than; at or before:
> 2. [on](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm)
>      use *on* to designate days and dates
> 3. [at](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm)
>      use *at* to designate specific times.

So,

1. *I have to go **by** 9 am*
   means the latest you can stay is 9 am. You have to leave at or before 9 am.
2. *I have to go **on** 9 am*
   does not make sense because *on* is used with **days** and **dates**.
3. *I have to go **at** 9 am*
   means you have to leave when the time is (exactly) 9 am.

---

To answer your follow-up question:

Use *before* when you have to leave **earlier** than 9 am.
Use *by* when you can leave specifically at 9 am or earlier.

*Till* is the informal version of *until*. *Until* has many uses, just like the on/at/by, but I think the main use here is

> [until](http://www.grammarbank.com/by-vs-until.html)
>   use until to talk about something that will keep going on for a duration of time from a specific time to another.

So "I have to leave *until* 9 am" doesn't really make sense. One might interpret this as you have to be *gone* or *absent* until 9 am. But as you can see, it has a completely different meaning than with the words *at* or *by*. You can say

> I have to **stay** until 9 am.

This means you have to stay. And when the time is 9 am, you are free to leave. Depending on the context, it might imply that you **will** leave at exactly 9 am.

Answer (score 2):

"By 9 am" means any time before 9 am.

"At 9 am" means at 9 am specifically.

We don't use "on" with time of day, but we do use it with days:

"On Monday" means sometime during Monday. "By Monday" means any time before Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Use **by** when some action or event needs to be completed before a specific date or time, but it is possible that it could happen earlier.

> > I must leave for the airport by 9:00 AM tomorrow

(allowing the possibility of leaving earlier)

> > We must complete this report by the end of July.

(allowing the possibility of completing it earlier)

When we have a specific date or time use **on** for a date, use **at** for a time.

> > We leave for our vacation on Tuesday 13th August.
> >
> > The train is due to arrive at 10:15 tomorrow morning.

we can use both on and at in the same sentence:

> > My flight leaves at noon on Wednesday 17th September.