# "Return" by usage

Tags: word-usage, sentence-combination

Just curious about the wording for **"Returning"** an item by a specific date

For example:

If I ask for an item to be **returned by** the 25th of May, does that mean I expect the item to be returned any day before the 26th of May.

If I ask for an item to be **returned before** the 25th of May, does that mean I expect the item to be returned any day upto and including the 24th of May.

If I ask for an item to be **returned after** the 25th of May, does that mean I expect the item to be returned after and including the 26th of May.

If I ask for an item to be **returned on** the 25th of May, I expect this to mean that the item must only be returned on that day, no sooner or later.

Comment: The specific verb ***returned*** is irrelevant here - all that matters is the preposition *(**by, before, after, on**)*. I think asking about the difference between ***before*** and ***after*** here is Off Topic (just look the words up), and other aspects of the question have been covered many times - for example [When to use 'by' instead of 'at' or 'on' to specify time/date?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94000/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica. Perfect, thanks for the link (It clarified my understanding of "by" which is going to be used in my form).

Comment: You can clarify it with "on or before 25th May."

Comment: @Weather Vane. Thanks. I would have clarified it as per your suggestion but the program is structured/limited to two words only "Returned ????", in the case of my selection "Returned By"