# Prepositions used when referring to a country's timezone: 7 o'clock at/by Moskow time

Tags: prepositions, articles, time

1. Let's meet at 7 o'clock at Moskow time
2. Let's meet at 7 o'clock by Moskow time

Is the first or the second one correct? If they are both inaccurate, can you please give a correct version?

And did I miss 'the' before 'Moskow time'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use 'by' instead of 'at' or 'on' to specify time/date?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94000/when-to-use-by-instead-of-at-or-on-to-specify-time-date) I think that [Em's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/94006/9161) in particular might be helpful.

Comment: In English, we spell the name of the Russian capital 'Moscow' with a 'c'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No preposition and no "the".  Simply "7 o'clock Moscow time"